# How do addresses that refer to a web site work?

Tags: address, blockchain.info

Some bitcoin addresses on blockchain.info refer to an external website, see e.g. here:

https://blockchain.info/tx/40c09e1fb345d258b8123c5e6ceda3d53575def3053c87bf7d5571c74fc2227d

One of the addresses in this transaction is:

https://blockchain.info/address/1bonesNcbrNbHJZr33LV2gBmDS9m91TWz

This blockchain.info page shows the address as English text instead of a Base58 encoded string.

How does this work?

Comment: Ah yes, it was already answered. Should I delete my question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tag to your address here https://blockchain.info/tags

It will be shown on bc.i site